Can not connect to oracle database from docker container running on local machine
I have a spring boot application running as docker container on my local machine. It is connecting to Oracle database which is there on our company datacenter. I am able to connect to database directly from my local machine using sql developer. However, the spring application running as docker container is giving the below error when connecting to database. I am sure it has to do something related to port mapping or networking in docker container.

Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection


Your db-container is mapped to port 1521 on your host-network. This is why SQL Developer will work using something like this: localhost:1521/SERVICE_NAME
SQL Developer has only access to the host-network and port 1521 is exposed to the host-network.
Now, you want your app-container to connect to the db-container.
The app container does not have access to the host-network (unless it is configured for host-mode), it has only access to the docker-network like 172.17.0.2/16
Solution
Find the ip of the database container in the docker-network:
docker container inspect free-23ai | grep '"IPAddress":'
        "IPAddress": "",
                "IPAddress": "172.21.0.2",

Now, you can build the connect string for your app.
172.21.0.2:1521/SERVICE_NAME

Tip
It is more convenient to use docker compose where service discovery is available.
services:
  app:
  db:

Now you can just configure your app like this:  db:1521/SERVICE_NAME or just db/SERVICE_NAME (1521 is default and can be ommitted)
Best of luck!

Hi. The database is not hosted on my local machine. Database is on my company datacenter and it is not running on container.. I am running the container on my local machine. I already have hardcoded the ip address of database server in connection string in java application. It still does not work. The strange thing is that when i ssh to container and do telnet to database IP from there, it is able to connect but when the java application tries to make connection to database it gives the error

In scenarios like this, I would make sure sqlplus is working from inside a container. This will verify the connectivity to the database from within the docker-network.
Since it is a corporate database, I would have checked the firewall log for dropped packages.
login
cat ~/.password | docker login container-registry.oracle.com --username first.last@gmail.com --password-stdin

one-liner for verification
docker run -ti --rm container-registry.oracle.com/database/instantclient sqlplus username@\"db-hostname:1521/SERVICE_NAME\"

Best of luck!

Hi. I installed sql client in docker container and was able to connect from sqlplus to Database from container. But my Spring boot application which is running inside the container gives the same error. Connection refused.  this is the url hardcoded in application.properties file.                                                                                   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(FAILOVER=YES)(LOAD_BALANCE=NO)(ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=YES)(FAILOVER=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.20.1.145)(PORT=15021)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ebs_SBD669))). Any idea

Make sure you can verify this: docker run -ti --rm container-registry.oracle.com/database/instantclient sqlplus username/password@"(DESCRIPTION=(FAILOVER=YES)(LOAD_BALANCE=NO)(ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=YES)(FAILOVER=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.20.1.145)(PORT=15021)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ebs_SBD669)))"
